# move the values from a normal array to a 2D array - What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, arrays

Basically I'm working on an assignment and I need to move the values from a normal array to a 2D array. I have to take input to set the length of the aray. The 2d array will be a square array, so say 3 is input my array needs to be 3x3. I've made the 1D array size `n*n`, with `n` being what the user inputs. I'm getting an index out of rage exception but I've gone through the code and written out what I think the values of everything should be at each stage and can't find out what's causing it.

```
public static void createTwoD(int[,] twoDArray, int[] startArray, int arrayLength)
{   
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++)
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
            twoDArray[i, x] = startArray[i * arrayLength + x];
}
```

The line getting the exception is the last line in that method. I'm passing in a 2D array of size [n,n], a 1D array of size [n*n] and the just n. If you want to see any more of the code let me know.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest putting curly braces to indicate the limits of your for loops - while not strictly needed it makes your code more readable and reduces the chance of making silly errors. ETA: there's no insult intended - we all make typos!

Comment: Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): a minimal example that demonstrates the behaviour you are having a problem with?

Comment: Are you sure that arrayLength is `n` and not `n*n`? Why would you even need that argument, when the array's length is written in the array object?

Comment: I don't understand your last line. What is it trying to do? At the moment I am guessing you are getting an outofbounds exception?

Comment: http://ideone.com/V337J2 seems to work just fine? Are you initializing your arrays properly?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that last line, run your code and inspect the values as it executes. You've said you've written out what you expect everything to be at each stage, but not that you've inspected what values everything *does* have at each stage. It is essential to know whether that line is failing on the first iteration (where x and i are both 0) or at some later point. It is saying `index out of range`, but what is the value of the index when this happens? This will help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you lines:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++)
       for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
          twoDArray[i, x] = startArray[i * arrayLength + x];
```

`arrayLength` variable makes jump out of bounds on `startArray`.  Note that both `x` and `i` are in range from `0` to `arrayLength`

If you know already dimensions of your 2d array, you can easily achieve this by (here I assume it 3x3):

```
var x = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   if(i!= 0 && i % 3 == 0) ++x; // go to another row

   twoDArray[i, x] = startArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding the following to the start of your method.  These document your assumptions about the dimensions of the arrays passed as arguments.

```
Debug.Assert(twoDArray.Rank == 2);
Debug.Assert(startArray.Rank == 1);
Debug.Assert(twoDArray.GetLength(0) == arrayLength);
Debug.Assert(twoDArray.GetLength(1) == arrayLength);
Debug.Assert(startArray.GetLength(0) == arrayLength * arrayLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe twoDArray issnt initilized correctly:

```
public static void createTwoD(int[,] twoDArray, int[] startArray, int arrayLength)
{
//twoDArray musst be initialized correctly, otherwise use:
twoDArray = new int[arrayLength][arrayLength];

for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++)
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
      twoDArray[i, x] = startArray[i * arrayLength + x];
}
```